# ffmpeg - overlay position at the end of the video is wrong

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to move a shape (an image) over a background image to each corner. [Here is the video example](https://local-banners.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/video/video-with-shape-overlay-issue.mp4) I generated with ffmpeg.

As you can see from the example, at the end of the video the shape is not positioned on the top right corner as it should be:

[image: last frame shape positionning issue]

Here is the ffmpeg command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i background.jpeg -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=300:250[s0];[1]format=gbrap[s4];[s0][s4]overlay=x=if(between(t\\,0.0\\,0.8)\\,lerp(0.0\\,240.0\\,round((t-0.0)/0.8*100)/100)\\,if(between(t\\,0.8\\,2.2)\\,lerp(240.0\\,0.0\\,round((t-0.8)/1.4*100)/100)\\,if(between(t\\,2.2\\,3.0)\\,lerp(0.0\\,240.0\\,round((t-2.2)/0.8*100)/100)))):y=if(between(t\\,0.0\\,0.8)\\,lerp(0.0\\,200.0\\,round((t-0.0)/0.8*100)/100)\\,if(between(t\\,0.8\\,2.2)\\,lerp(200.0\\,200.0\\,round((t-0.8)/1.4*100)/100)\\,if(between(t\\,2.2\\,3.0)\\,lerp(200.0\\,0.0\\,round((t-2.2)/0.8*100)/100))))[s5]" -map "[s5]" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 3.0 video.mp4
```

- video is 300x250
- logo.png is the blue shape (width=60px, height=50px)
- the coordinates are set as follow: 0s: x=0,y=0 / 0.8s: x=240px,y=200px / 2.2s: x=0,y=200px / 3s: x=240px,y=0

I am using `lerp` to retrieve the right position depending on the current time `t`.
It seems like the last frames are not played.

I tried to:

- set a framerate (30 & 100) to the logo.png input,
- round the value given by lerp,
- use setpts to define a number of frames.

But I do not understand the problem I am facing, could you help me?

**UPDATE 1**: If I extend the video duration to 4s, the shape position at 3s is the right one

**UPDATE 2**: I added `-framerate 100` as option the logo.png input and `fps=24` just after the *scale* filter. The problem is still present. I extracted every frame as png (as expected there are 72 frames) & 17 were generated between 2.2s & 3s.

**UPDATE 3**: The problem is resolved by settings a `fps` of *100*. However the generated video file is too big. Is there any other way to get it to work at 24fps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your total duration is 3 seconds, there is no frame *at* 3 seconds. The last frame is at 3 seconds - *1/framerate* seconds.

The default framerate of image inputs is 25, so you should interpolate to the final position at 2.96 seconds.

i.e.

`if(between(t\\,2.2\\,3.0)\\, lerp(200.0\\,0.0\\,round((t-2.2)/0.76*100)/100))`

Comment: Thank you, that's working. Can you tell me why "The last frame is at 3 seconds - 1/framerate seconds"? (Is this a FFmpeg limitation?)

Comment: No. Each frame has a presentation time and a duration. For 25 fps videos, duration is 1/25 = 40ms. If there was a frame at 3s, then total video duration would be 3s40ms.

Comment: oh that makes perfect sense! thank you